# python: super()-like proxy object that starts the MRO search at a specified class

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, superclass, super

According to the docs, `super(cls, obj)` returns

> a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling
>   class of type cls

I understand why `super()` offers this functionality, but I need something slightly different: I need to create a proxy object that delegates methods calls (and attribute lookups) to class `cls` itself; and as in `super`, if `cls` doesn't implement the method/attribute, my proxy should continue looking in the MRO order (of the *new* not the *original* class). Is there any function I can write that achieves that?

Example:

```
class X:
  def act():
    #...

class Y:
  def act():
    #...

class A(X, Y):
  def act():
    #...

class B(X, Y):
  def act():
    #...

class C(A, B):
  def act():
    #...

c = C()
b = some_magic_function(B, c)
# `b` needs to delegate calls to `act` to B, and look up attribute `s` in B
# I will pass `b` somewhere else, and have no control over it
```

Of course, I could do `b = super(A, c)`, but that relies on knowing the exact class hierarchy **and** the fact that `B` follows `A` in the MRO. It would silently break if any of these two assumptions change in the future. (Note that `super` doesn't make any such assumptions!)

If I just needed to call `b.act()`, I could use `B.act(c)`. But I am passing `b` to someone else, and have no idea what they'll do with it. I need to make sure it doesn't betray me and start acting like an instance of `class C` at some point.

A separate question, the documentation for `super()` (in Python 3.2) only talks about its method delegation, and does not clarify that attribute lookups for the proxy are also performed the same way. Is it an accidental omission?

EDIT

The updated Delegate approach works in the following example as well:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print('A.f')
    def h(self):
        print('A.h')
        self.f()

class B(A):
    def g(self):
        self.f()
        print('B.g')
    def f(self):
        print('B.f')
    def t(self):
        super().h()


a_true = A()
# instance of A ends up executing A.f
a_true.h()

b = B()
a_proxy = Delegate(A, b)
# *unlike* super(), the updated `Delegate` implementation would call A.f, not B.f
a_proxy.h()
```

Note that the updated `class Delegate` is closer to what I want than `super()` for two reasons:

1. `super()` only does it proxying for the first call; subsequent calls will happen as normal, since by then the object is used, not its proxy.
2. `super()` does not allow attribute access.

Thus, my question as asked has a (nearly) perfect answer in Python.

It turns out that, at a higher level, I was trying to do something I shouldn't ([see my comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886568/is-it-wrong-trying-to-suppress-overriding-on-a-case-by-case-basis)).

Comment: You can't make sure it doesn't act like an instance of class C, because that's what it is. If you really, seriously want an instance of B(), I recommend you simply make an instance of B with the attributes needed. You can copy them from C.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: well, I didn't require that `b` is an instance of `class C`, and in fact it's not; it is an instance of a completely different class (`class Delegate` in case of Sven's solution, `class super` in case of built-in `super()`, and so on). That aside, you may be right that `b` can't be prevented from betraying its ability to (indirectly) access `class C` instance methods and attributes. If so, can you give an example of how Sven's `Delegate(B, c)` would act as an instance of `class C`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class should cover the most common cases:

```
class Delegate:
    def __init__(self, cls, obj):
        self._delegate_cls = cls
        self._delegate_obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        x = getattr(self._delegate_cls, name)
        if hasattr(x, "__get__"):
            return x.__get__(self._delegate_obj)
        return x
```

Use it like this:

```
b = Delegate(B, c)
```

(with the names from your example code.)

Restrictions:

1. You cannot retrieve some special attributes like `__class__` etc. from the class you pass in the constructor via this proxy.  (This restistions also applies to `super`.)
2. This might behave weired if the attribute you want to retrieve is some weired kind of descriptor.

**Edit**: If you want the code in the update to your question to work as desired, you can use the foloowing code:

```
class Delegate:
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._delegate_cls = cls
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        x = getattr(self._delegate_cls, name)
        if hasattr(x, "__get__"):
            return x.__get__(self)
        return x
```

This passes the proxy object as `self` parameter to any called method, and it doesn't need the original object at all, hence I deleted it from the constructor.

If you also want instance attributes to be accessible you can use this version:

```
class Delegate:
    def __init__(self, cls, obj):
        self._delegate_cls = cls
        self._delegate_obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in vars(self._delegate_obj):
            return getattr(self._delegate_obj, name)
        x = getattr(self._delegate_cls, name)
        if hasattr(x, "__get__"):
            return x.__get__(self)
        return x
```

Comment: I just updated the question, since it turns out I actually pass `b` to someone else. This means that my `functools` solution no longer works. It seems that what you're doing precisely meets my needs, let me just test it a bit. I assume I just say `b = Delegate(B, c)`?

Comment: This doesn't behave like `super` in the presence of multiple inheritance. It delegates to the MRO of `_delegate_cls`, regardless of where it sits in the full MRO of `_delegate_obj`. In fact it delegates to `_delegate_cls` regardless of whether it's even **in** the full MRO of `_delegate_obj`, which is interesting. :) But given that the OP explicitly talked about multiple inheritance and MROs, that may not be desired. It also doesn't support attribute lookup at all (neither does `super` mind you).

Comment: Ah yeah, we'd need to check  cls is in the MRO, and also if method not found in cls, start the search from next class in MRO AFTER cls

Comment: @Ben: I'm not sure if it really would be desired to use the MRO of the original object.

Comment: @Max: Delegate uses `getattr()` to look up an attribute in `cls`.  This automatically means that all base classes of `cls` are also searched.  As Ben remarked, this is different from the clases that come after `cls` in the MRO of the original object, but I'm not sure this is what you really want.

Comment: @Max Yes, having read more about what you're is trying to do (from the other questions), it seems like `Delegate` is a better fit for your requirements than "skipping to a certain point in the MRO" like `super` does. With new code to handle attribute access, you should probably accept this answer again.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Ah, clever to pass the wrapper as `self`. I hadn't thought that would work without convolutions to make the wrapper class a subclass of the class you're delegating too (which is also possible), and indeed it doesn't work in Python2, but Python3 has removed the restriction that `self` needs to be an instance of the class.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, that strange notion of an "unbound method" luckily is gone in Python 3.  It was quite against the duck-typing spirit of Python.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify in my original question what to do if `B` doesn't have the method: continue the search of the MRO of the class of the original `delegate_obj`, or search the MRO of `delegate_cls`. I suppose if I *was* trying to pretend that `Delegate(B,c)` is really of class `B`, I'd search the MRO of `B`, which is what you've done.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if passing `self` to the method might work, but just thinking about it totally confused me. And the answer seems to be "yes" in my Python 3, but not in old Python! I'm glad I don't have to understand why it didn't work in Python 2.

Comment: Questions about the proposed solution: 1. Doesn't `__get__` require 2 arguments (apart from `self`)? 2. Shouldn't we use `__get_attribute__` instead of `__getattr__`? 3. I assume I should add the check that `delegate_cls` is in the MRO of `delegate_obj`.

Comment: @max: 1. The last argument of `__get__()` is optional and unneeded in this case. 2. I deliberately chose `__getattr__()` because it simplifies the access to the attributes `_delegate_cls` and `_delegate_obj`. 3. I would not add such a check unless strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> A separate question, the documentation for super() (in Python 3.2)
>   only talks about its method delegation, and does not clarify that
>   attribute lookups for the proxy are also performed the same way. Is it
>   an accidental omission?

No, this is not accidental. `super()` does nothing for attribute lookups. The reason is that attributes on an instance are not associated with a particular class, they're just there. Consider the following:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'foo set from A'

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bar = 'bar set from B'

class C(B):
    def method(self):
        self.baz = 'baz set from C'

class D(C):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo = 'foo set from D'
        self.baz = 'baz set from D'

instance = D()
instance.method()
instance.bar = 'not set from a class at all'
```

Which class "owns" `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`?

If I wanted to view `instance` as an instance of C, should it have a `baz` attribute before `method` is called? How about afterwards?

If I view `instance` as an instance of A, what value should `foo` have? Should `bar` be invisible because was only added in B, or visible because it was set to a value outside the class?

All of these questions are nonsense in Python. There's no possible way to design a system with the semantics of Python that could give sensible answers to them. `__init__` isn't even special in terms of adding attributes to instances of the class; it's just a perfectly ordinary method that happens to be called as part of the instance creation protocol. Any method (or indeed code from another class altogether, or not from any class at all) can create attributes on any instance it has a reference to.

In fact, all of the attributes of `instance` are stored in the same place:

```
>>> instance.__dict__
{'baz': 'baz set from C', 'foo': 'foo set from D', 'bar': 'not set from a class at all'}
```

There's no way to tell which of them were originally set by which class, or were last set by which class, or whatever measure of ownership you want. There's certainly no way to get at "the `A.foo` being shadowed by `D.foo`", as you would expect from C++; they're the same attribute, and any writes to to it by one class (or from elsewhere) will clobber a value left in it by the other class.

The consequence of this is that `super()` does not perform attribute lookups the same way it does method lookups; it can't, and neither can any code you write.

---

In fact, from running some experiments, neither `super` nor Sven's `Delegate` actually support direct attribute retrieval at all!

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spoon = 1
        self.fork = 2

    def foo(self):
        print('A.foo')

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print('B.foo')

b = B()

d = Delegate(A, b)
s = super(B, b)
```

Then both work as expected for methods:

```
>>> d.foo()
A.foo
>>> s.foo()
A.foo
```

But:

```
>>> d.fork
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    d.fork
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 6, in __getattr__
    x = getattr(self._delegate_cls, name)
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'fork'
>>> s.spoon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
    s.spoon
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'spoon'
```

So they both only really work for calling some methods on, not for passing to arbitrary third party code to pretend to be an instance of the class you want to delegate to.

They don't behave the same way in the presence of multiple inheritance unfortunately. Given:

```
class Delegate:
    def __init__(self, cls, obj):
        self._delegate_cls = cls
        self._delegate_obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        x = getattr(self._delegate_cls, name)
        if hasattr(x, "__get__"):
            return x.__get__(self._delegate_obj)
        return x


class A:
    def foo(self):
        print('A.foo')

class B:
    pass

class C(B, A):
    def foo(self):
        print('C.foo')

c = C()

d = Delegate(B, c)
s = super(C, c)
```

Then:

```
>>> d.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    d.foo()
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 6, in __getattr__
    x = getattr(self._delegate_cls, name)
AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'foo'
>>> s.foo()
A.foo
```

Because `Delegate` ignores the full MRO of whatever class `_delegate_obj` is an instance of, only using the MRO of `_delegate_cls`. Whereas `super` does what you asked in the question, but the behaviour seems quite strange: it's not wrapping an instance of C to pretend it's an instance of B, because direct instances of B don't have `foo` defined.

Here's my attempt:

```
class MROSkipper:
    def __init__(self, cls, obj):
        self.__cls = cls
        self.__obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        mro = self.__obj.__class__.__mro__
        i = mro.index(self.__cls)
        if i == 0:
            # It's at the front anyway, just behave as getattr
            return getattr(self.__obj, name)
        else:
            # Check __dict__ not getattr, otherwise we'd find methods
            # on classes we're trying to skip
            try:
                return self.__obj.__dict__[name]
            except KeyError:
                return getattr(super(mro[i - 1], self.__obj), name)
```

I rely on the `__mro__` attribute of classes to properly figure out where to start from, then I just use `super`. You could walk the MRO chain from that point yourself checking class `__dict__`s for methods instead if the weirdness of going back one step to use `super` is too much.

I've made no attempt to handle unusual attributes; those implemented with descriptors (including properties), or those magic methods looked up behind the scenes by Python, which often start at the class rather than the instance directly. But this behaves as you asked moderately well (with the caveat expounded on ad nauseum in the first part of my post; looking up attributes this way will not give you any different results than looking them up directly in the instance).

Comment: `super` and `Delegate` don't handle instance attributes because it wouldn't make much sense to do so.  They both *do* handle class attributes correctly, though.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It does for the OP's stated purpose of bundling up an instance which implements methods starting further up in the MRO, to then pass to other code that has no knowledge it's getting a wrapper. Often, but not always, the other code will manipulate the object purely through methods, so you'd want to be able to retrieve attributes as well.

Comment: @Ben: thanks, this really helps me understand why `super()` doesn't work with attribute lookups. And I do understand the code you use for looking up methods in the original MRO; for my purposes, I do want the new MRO to be used for my purposes.