# can overriding of a method be prevented by downcasting to a superclass?

Tags: oop, class, inheritance, overriding, method-hiding

I'm trying to understand whether the answer to the following question is the same in all major OOP languages; and if not, then how do those languages differ.

Suppose I have class `A` that defines methods `act` and `jump`; method `act` calls method `jump`. `A`'s subclass `B` overrides method `jump` (i.e., the appropriate syntax is used to ensure that whenever `jump` is called, the implementation in class `B` is used).

I have object `b` of class `B`. I want it to behave exactly as if it was of class `A`. In other words, I want the `jump` to be performed using the implementation in `A`. What are my options in different languages?

For example, can I achieve this with some form of downcasting? Or perhaps by creating a proxy object that knows which methods to call?

I would want to avoid creating a brand new object of class `A` and carefully setting up the  sharing of internal state between `a` and `b` because that's obviously not future-proof, and complicated. I would also want to avoid copying the state of `b` into a brand new object of class `A` because there might be a lot of data to copy.

UPDATE

I asked this question [specifically about Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840082/python-super-like-proxy-object-that-starts-the-mro-search-at-a-specified-clas/8840347#8840347), <strike>but it seems this is impossible to achieve in Python</strike> and technically it can be done... kinda..

It appears that apart from technical feasibility, there's a strong argument against doing this from a design perspective. I'm asking about that in [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886568/whats-wrong-with-trying-to-suppress-overriding-on-a-case-by-case-basis).

Comment: Indeed - in Python the concept of casting does not even exist. It is possible to hack a good deal of introspection to have it working - but I suppose that in other dynamic languages it should not be possible as well.

Comment: Delegate the implementations of act and jump to some other class (Strategy perhaps), then don't bother with B. Generally, if your existing design has you looking for ways to circumvent good OO design, it's time to take a step back and ask why.

Comment: @TerryWilcox: but can't this problem arise, potentially, with any inheritance with dynamic binding? In that case, I (potentially) have to be ready to refactor any code from inheritance to some other approach whenever this problem comes up. This would makes the prospect of using polymorphism very unattractive. What am I missing?

Comment: Subclassing is all about changing behaviour. If you want your instance b to act as if it's an A, then it shouldn't be a B in the first place. If I was in your situation, I'd accept that inheritance was a bad design and switch to composition. e.g There is just A, which uses the strategy pattern to implement different behaviours.

Comment: @TerryWilcox: so would you say that it's unlikely that one might need to suppress polymorphism; but if in my application I see it as a distinct possibility, I should try to use Strategy pattern instead, which is strictly more powerful, but comes at a slightly higher coding cost?

Comment: You're not suppressing polymorphism, you're suppressing inheritance. And if you need to suppress it, you shouldn't use it to begin with. "Prefer composition over inheritance" is a good design philosophy. Inheritance is not always appropriate and trying to hack the underlying OO mechanisms to make a design work is a huge warning sign.

Comment: @TerryWilcox can you put your comments into an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments reiterated: Prefer composition over inheritance.

Inheritance works well when your subclasses have well defined behavioural differences from their superclass, but you'll frequently hit a point where that model gets awkward or stops making sense. At that point, you need to reconsider your design.

Composition is usually the better solution. Delegating your object's varying behaviour to a different object (or objects) may reduce or eliminate your need for subclassing.

In your case, the behavioural differences between class A and class B could be encapsulated in the Strategy pattern. You could then change the behaviour of class A (and class B, if still required) at the instance level, simply by assigning a new strategy.

The Strategy pattern may require more code in the short run, but it's clean and maintainable. Method swizzling, monkey patching, and all those cool things that allow us to poke around in our specific language implementation are fun, but the potential for unexpected side effects is high and the code tends to be difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is completely unrelated/unsupported by OOP programming.

If you subclass an object `A` with class `B` and override its methods, when a concrete instance of `B` is created then all the overriden/new implementation of the base methods are associated with it (either we talk about Java or C++ with virtual tables etc).

You have instantiated object `B`.
Why would you expect that you could/would/should be able to call the method of the superclass if you have overriden that method?

You could call it explicitely of course e.g. by calling `super` inside the method, but you can not do it automatically, and casting will not help you do that either.

I can't imagine why you would want to do that.
If you need to use class `A` then use class `A`.
If you need to override its functionality then use its subclass `B`.

Comment: I can't tell you why a language like C++ supports non-virtual methods, off hand, but it does.

Comment: `virtual` is used in C++ to declare that a function can be overriden.Once the function is declared `virtual` then the method of the subclass is run at runtime.I.e. polymorphism is not running by default as in Java. But this is not related to the question of the OP

Comment: @user384706: yes, my question is whether something can (and should) be done once the override is already enabled in the class definition (in the case of C++, `virtual` keyword is used).

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages go to some trouble to support dynamic dispatch of virtual functions (the case of calling the overridden method `jump` in a subclass instead of the parent class's implementation) -- to the degree that working around it or avoiding it is difficult.  In general, specialization/polymorphism is a desirable feature -- arguably a goal of OOP in the first place.

Take a look at the Wikipedia article on [Virtual Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function), which gives a useful overview of the support for virtual functions in many programming languages.  It will give you a place to start when considering a specific language, as well as the trade-offs to weigh when looking at a language where the programmer can control how dispatch behaves (see the section on C++, for example).

So loosely, the answer to your question is, "No, the behavior is not the same in all programming languages."  Furthermore, there is no language independent solution.  C++ may be your best bet if you **need** the behavior.

Comment: Without `virtual` polyphormism does not work in C++.This is not what the OP is asking.It is the same as the subclass never defined the method

Comment: It sounds exactly like OP is asking for a non-virtual method call (a la C++).

Comment: You are missing the point.If the method is non-virtual it is the same as never being overriden. I.e. only the class A method is called. Never of class B. The OP wants to call method of class B and sometime if he wants to, call method of class A as well.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.  @user384706: you are correct, I don't want to modify the class definition. Even if I could replace virtual with non-virtual methods in class A, it won't work, since then many other users of class B passed as class A object will be badly surprised when class B starts to behave like class A.

Comment: @max:So you have a use case?It is not a theoritical question?What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't make this question any more verbose without confusing everyone. So I made a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886568/is-it-wrong-trying-to-suppress-overriding-on-a-case-by-case-basis

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with Python (sort of), with some awful hacks. It requires that you implement something like the wrappers we were discussing in your first Python-specific question, but *as a subclass of B*. You then need to implement write-proxying as well (the wrapper object shouldn't contain any of the state normally associated with the class hierarchy, it should redirect all attribute access to the underlying instance of B.

But rather than redirecting method lookup to A and then calling the method with the wrapped instance, you'd call the method passing the wrapper object as `self`. This is legal because the wrapper class is a subclass of B, so the wrapper instance is an instance of the classes whose methods you're calling.

This would be very strange code, requiring you to dynamically generate classes using both IS-A and HAS-A relationships at the same time. It would probably also end up fairly fragile and have bizarre results in a lot of corner cases (you generally can't write 100% perfect wrapper classes in Python exactly because this sort of strange thing is possible).

I'm completely leaving aside weather this is a good idea or not.