# Python2 __bases__ and super

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, super, diamond-problem

In Python 2.7, I am trying to reconstruct AN inheritance chain from a certain class `E` to the root `A`. There is a diamond inheritance problem as shown below, but I am interested in a path, not THE path, so it should work. Whether it's something I should be doing (this way) is questionable, but right now I just want to know what I am misunderstanding...

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def supah(thisCls):
        return [cls for cls in thisCls.__bases__ if issubclass(cls, A)]
    def name(self):
        return 'A'

class C(A):
    def name(self):
        return 'C'

class D(A):
    def name(self):
        return 'D'

class E(C, D):
    def name(self):
        return 'E'

current = E
while True:
    try:
        print current, super(current, E()), super(current, E()).name()
    except AttributeError:
        break
    current = current.supah()[0]
```

The output

```
<class '__main__.E'> <super: <class 'E'>, <E object>> C
<class '__main__.C'> <super: <class 'C'>, <E object>> D
<class '__main__.A'> <super: <class 'A'>, <E object>>
```

What is D doing there? It is calling

```
super(C, E()).name()
```

where `super(C, E())` should be "class A", right? If the C on the first line had been an D I would have (sort of) understood, but in my mind the second line should definitely be an A.

Any help?

**EDIT**: My understanding was that calling

```
super(C, obj).name()
```

would result in the name "A", because the linearization of C is `[C, A, object]`.

However, this is not what `super(C, obj).name()` means apparently. It still uses the full linearization of obj: `[E, C, D, A, object]` (thanks to @Martijn Pieters), it just starts at (after) C. Therefore D comes before A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super()` doesn't look at `__bases__`; it looks at the Method Resolution Order (MRO), through `type(self).mro()`:

```
>>> E.mro()
[<class '__main__.E'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>]
```

As you can see, `D` is in there, because it is a base class of `E`; when you call `super(C, E()).name()`, `D` comes next in the MRO.

The MRO will always include *all* base classes in a hierarchy; you cannot build a class hierarchy where the MRO could not be established. This to prevent classes being skipped in a diamond inheritance pattern.

How the MRO works is explained in detail in [*The Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order*](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

You may also want to read [Guido van Rossum's explanation](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html); he uses a diamond pattern with:

```
class A:
  def save(self): pass

class B(A): pass

class C(A):
  def save(self): pass

class D(B, C): pass
```

to illustrate why an MRO is important; when calling `D().save()` you'd want `C.save()` to be invoked (more specialized), *not* `A.save()`.

If you really wanted to *skip* `D` from `C.name`, you'd have to explicitly find `C.__bases__[0]` in the MRO, then tell `super()` to start search for the next `.name()` method from there:

```
mro = type(self).mro()
preceding = mro[0]
for i, cls in enumerate(mro[1:], 1):
    if cls in self.__bases__:
        preceding = mro[i - 1]
name = super(preceding, self).name()
```

For your `E.mro()` and class `C`, this'll find `D`, as it precedes the first base class of `C`, `A`. Calling `super(D, self).name()` then tells `super()` to find the first class past `D` with a `name()` method, which is `A` here.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the link because it seems very illogical right now.

Comment: @Mark: then in your mental model, what should happen if `C` does *not* define a `name()` method? So all classes *except* `C` have a `name()` method; what `name()` method should be called when you call `super(E, E()).name()`?

Comment: Thanks, I think I misunderstand `super` rather than the MRO; updated my question.

Comment: @Mark: That's why my post starts with `type(self).mro()`; the type of the second argument is used as the source for the MRO; the first argument is merely the starting point for `super()` to start the search from.

Comment: @Mark: Now that you know how `super()` works, what is the remaining question here? Did my answer address that question yet? If not, it is not clear what question you still have.

Comment: I think this question is answered. I'm curious how to achieve the effect I thought I was implementing, but that should be a new question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Mark: If you really wanted to *skip* `D` you'd have to inspect the current MRO and find the preceding class before the first class in `C.__bases__` and tell `super()` to start from there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Martijn Pieters explains how the observed result is produced.

In case one wants to produce the result that I was incorrectly expecting from super, one might use an approach based on the accepted answer from @Sven Marnach on [python: super()-like proxy object that starts the MRO search at a specified class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840082/python-super-like-proxy-object-that-starts-the-mro-search-at-a-specified-clas)

If you want to get something that behalves as a class `A` version of a `C` instance:

```
class Delegate:
    def __init__(self, cls, obj):
        self._delegate_cls = cls
        self._delegate_obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        x = getattr(self._delegate_cls, name)
        if hasattr(x, "__get__"):
            return x.__get__(self._delegate_obj)
        return x
```

which can be used to get `.name()` from `A` like this:

```
class C(A):
    def name(self):
        return delegate(A, self).name() + 'C'
C().name()
# result: AC
```

If you are interested in a super-like construct that gets a (the first) direct ancestor:

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self, cls, obj):
        if len(cls.__bases__):
            self._delegate_cls = cls.__bases__[0]
        else:
            raise Exception('parent called for class "%s", which has no base classes')
        self._delegate_obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        x = getattr(self._delegate_cls, name)
        if hasattr(x, '__get__'):
            return x.__get__(self._delegate_obj)
        return x
```

called like this:

```
class C(A):
    def name(self):
        return parent(C, self).name() + 'C'
print C().name()
# result: AC
```

I don't think there is a way to not explicitly include the name of the current class, just like `super` (in py2).

Note that this is for special cases. E.g. in my example if `C` doesn't implement `.name()` it calls the one on `A`, never `D`. It does however let you get a (not 'the') direct ancestor line from a class to the root. Also, `parent(Cls, obj)` will always be a parent of `obj`, not a class that `Cls` known nothing about but which happens to be an ancestor of `obj`.